# Equivalent definitions of continuity at a point

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I'm going with a definition of a map over defined on topological spaces $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous at a point $x\in X$ 
is as follows:

> $f$ is continuous at each element $x\in X$ if and only if for every 
>   $V$ is open in $Y$  with $f(x)\in V$ there is an open set $U_x\subset X$ with $x\in U_x$ 
>   and $f(U_x)\subset V$ or equivalently $U_x\subset f^{-1}(V)$.

Let $\overline{A}$ be the closure of a subset $A$
in $X$.

> Prove that a map $f$ from a topological space $X$
>   to a topological space $Y$ is continuous 
>   at a point $x_{0}$ in $X$
>   if and only if
>   $f(x_{0}) \in \overline{f(M)}$ for any subset $M$ in $X$
>   such that $x_{0} \in \overline{M}$.

I'm having trouble how to get started with the problem.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to show that both definitions are equivalent you have to show that each of them implies the other one.

Let us first assume that $f$ is continuous at $x_0 \in X$ and let $M \subseteq X$ be a subset with $x_0 \in \overline{M}$. Recall that this means that every open subset containing $x_0$ intersects $M$ nontrivially. We want to show that $f(x_0) \in \overline{f(M)}$, so we have to show that every open subset of $Y$ which contains $f(x_0)$ intersects $f(M)$ nontrivially. In fact if $V$ is such an open subset then continuity implies $f(U) \subseteq V$ for some open subset $U$ of $X$ which contains $x_0$. Now use $x_0 \in \overline{M}$ and $f(U) \subseteq V$ to conclude that $V \cap f(M)$ is not empty.

For the other direction, we want to show that if $f$ is not continuous in $x_0$, then we find a subset $M$ of $X$ such that $x_0 \in \overline{M}$ but  $f(x_0) \notin \overline{f(M)}$. That $f$ is not continuous at $x_0$ means that there exists an open subset $V$ of $Y$ such that $f^{-1}(V)$ does not contain any open subset of $X$ which contains $x_0$. You might want to consider $M = X \setminus{f^{-1}(V)}$ now.

Comment: In your second paragraph, why "every open subset containing $x_0$ intersects $M$ nontrivially"? We just know $x_0 \in \overline{M}$. Shouldn't it be "every open subset containing $x_0$ intersects $\overline{M}$ nontrivially"?

Comment: @user : No, I mean it the way I wrote it. If $U$ is an open subset of $X$ for which $M \cap U$ is empty, then $X\setminus{U}$ is a closed subset of $X$ containing $M$ and so $\overline{M} \subseteq X\setminus{U}$ and this implies that $\overline{M} \cap U$ is empty, too.

Comment: I see. My next question: Why $x_0 \in \overline{M}$ and $f(U) \subseteq V$ implies $V \cap f(M)$ is not empty? I tried to use a similar way to yours above. If $V \cap f(M)=\emptyset$, then $\overline{f(M)} \subseteq Y\setminus V$. This implies that $V \cap\overline{f(M)}=\emptyset$. No contradiction can be found?

Comment: Since $x_0 \in \overline{M}$, the intersection $M \cap U$ is not empty. Note that the image under $f$ of this intersection is a subset of $V \cap f(M)$.

Comment: My last question: in the third paragraph I understand that $x_0 \in \overline{M}$ but why $f(x_0) \notin \overline{f(M)}$?

Comment: If $f(x_0)$ were in the closure of $f(M)$ then every open subset of $Y$ containing $f(x_0)$ would have to intersect $f(M)$ nontrivially. But $V \cap f(M)$ is empty, so $f(x_0) \notin \overline{f(M)}$.

Comment: I fully understand now. Thanks for very nice lectures.

Answer (score 0):

To prove that continuity implies that $x_0 \in \overline{M} \implies f(x_0) \in \overline{f(M)}$, you should use the definition of continuity: what can you take from it? Does it state something about relationships among sets of $Y$ and $X$? Can you take them and use the closures?